# Moving threads across CPUs with clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)

Tags: linux, windows, multithreading, winapi, posix

I've heard people complain that the WinAPI functions QueryPerformanceFrequency() and QueryPerforamnceCounter() can behave erratically and unstably when the OS decides to move the calling thread to a new physical CPU.

Does anybody know if clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC) suffers from similar issues? Or is it more guaranteed to be stable?

Also, are the worries about QPF/QPC on WinAPI just a thing of the past? Or are they still concerns even today?

Answer (score 0):

OP:

> I've heard people complain that the WinAPI functions QueryPerformanceFrequency() and QueryPerforamnceCounter() can behave erratically and unstably when the OS decides to move the calling thread to a new physical CPU.

I'm not sure what you mean by "erratic" or "unstable."  If you mean drift, or variance between cores, these concerns are probably based on computers that shipped 12-15 years ago (XP and Win2000-based OS).  From Microsoft:

> QPC is available on Windows XP and Windows 2000 and works well on most systems. However, some hardware systems' BIOS didn't indicate the hardware CPU characteristics correctly (a non-invariant TSC), and some multi-core or multi-processor systems used processors with TSCs that couldn't be synchronized across cores. Systems with flawed firmware that run these versions of Windows might not provide the same QPC reading on different cores if they used the TSC as the basis for QPC.

That has pretty much become a non-issue for most current hardware (see link, below).

OP:

> Does anybody know if clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC) suffers from similar issues? Or is it more guaranteed to be stable?

Well, any high-frequency clock has to come from *somewhere*.   On a Windows box (since you asked about QPC), where is that value going to come from?  Adding an additional layer to any call to QueryPerformanceCounter essentially **guarantees** less precision, as there will be more CPU instructions in the mix between "*now*" and "*now as reported back to you by the OS*" (and, although extremely unlikely, there would be a small increase in the possibility of preemption, contributing further loss of precision).

This applies equally to any Intel-based Linux/BSD/whatever boxes, as they have to run with the same hardware characteristics.  In the Intel-architecture world, the highest frequency you'll be able to get is going to be a value based on RDTSC and the operating system's best effort to keep any TSC values as close as possible across cores or processors (at least in the absence of specialized hardware).

This is why any benchmarking should be an *average* performance expectation based on a large number of data points.

Microsoft actually has a pretty good document outlining the implementation characteristics of high-frequency timers, including HPET and ACPI power management times, and touches briefly on multi-clock and virtualization: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx.

OP:

> Also, are the worries about QPF/QPC on WinAPI just a thing of the past? Or are they still concerns even today?

For most of the world, yes.  I work on server-based code where *microseconds* count (high frequency market data), but most people who think a few hundred microseconds are going to make or break their program are kidding themselves.  Do you know how *long* it takes to serve a web page?  The CPU itself gets bored with all that waiting, even with thousands of users.